# É possível excluir tags com erro de digitação?

Tags: debate, suporte, tags

Vi duas perguntas no site que usam tags que possuem erro de digitação:

[Simular eventos de teclas em javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/12844/3117) - A tag diz `javacript` quando era para ser `javascript`.

[Por que o polimorfismo não funciona com Genéricos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8679/3117) - A tag diz `polimorifismo` quando era para ser `polimorfismo`.

Consertar a tag beleza, mas dá para excluir a errada para que novas perguntas não sejam criadas com a tag errada por acidente?

Comment: CorriJido :D :D

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Vi uma [pergunta similar no Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19753/how-can-we-get-rid-of-misspelled-and-unused-or-zombie-tags). Tags que não tenham perguntas associadas são eliminadas diariamente, então corrigir a tag na(s) pergunta(s) é suficiente na maior parte dos casos.

Comment: O pessoal do SE pensou em tudo mesmo =)