# Solicitação de remoção da tag [Debate] no site principal

Tags: debate, status-pronto, tags, tag-específica

A tag [debate](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/debate) no site principal parece ter sido criada por engano há coisa de uns dias atrás por uma pergunta que foi migrada aqui para o meta devido ao seu contexto. No entanto, esta tag continua a permanecer lá, o que vai incentivar novos usuários a usufruir da sua utilização.

Normalmente, ela [deveria de ser eliminida](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1263). Mas como se trata de uma pergunta que foi migrada para o meta, a tag parece não ter sido removida. Não sei como é que a "remoção de tag automática" funciona nesses casos, mas eu penso que ela merecia a atenção dos moderadores para a sua remoção, para evitar a sua utilização no futuro.

Comment: A Própria pergunta usou a tag **debate**, que ironia...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Obrigado por teres reparado neste problema. Apaguei a pergunta lá no site e assim a tag deve desaparecer dentro de dias/horas.